# PHP cURL Cancel Subscription PayPal issues

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I will admit, I have been on this for 3 days, back and forth through documentation, and even learned how to create my own products and plans through Postman.

So I have a complete working subscription button, now I learned I need to save the Subscription ID in order to cancel the subscription so now that is saving and loading perfectly.

To my sad surprise, I need to get an AuthKey every time someone wants to cancel, so I need to run 2 cURL commands, 1 GET Auth Key, and 1 POST cancel a subscription. How would I do this in PHP?

I don't get any errors when these commands run just no data.

Paypal cURL Example:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_cancel

```
////////////////////////////// GET TEMP ACCESS TOKEN/////////////////////////////////
$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "x";
$secret = "x";
$myIDKEY = "";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json->access_token);
    $myIDKEY = $json->access_token;
}

curl_close($ch);

/////////////////////////////// SEND CANCEL POST ////////////////////////////////
$ch = curl_init();
$headers  = [
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$myIDKEY, 
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];
$postData = [
    'reason' => 'clicked cancel subscription button'
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/".$_SESSION['honeybeesubID']."/cancel");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result     = curl_exec ($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


echo $myIDKEY
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code gave me a good start, thanks Sebastian. The docs are pretty hard to read... especially with missing PHP Code. Can you point out how to create a subscription? Have you implemented the ready-made Javascript code from the paypal page, and then some webhook to get the subscription ID of the client? ... In your code it is called `$_SESSION['honeybeesubID']`. I want to save the subscription ID in the database after sign-up. -- The docs at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/#3-create-payment-button do not say where/how to get the customer ID to identify him later on.

Comment: Alright, the PHP script that is defined at the webhook URL can read the incoming data by `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
error_log(print_r($data, true));`

Comment: I have written a complete tutorial now, since all of it was pretty difficult: https://www.stacklounge.de/6325/tutorial-integrate-paypal-subscription-javascript-complete

Answer (score 1):

As documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_cancel , a success response is an HTTP 204 with no data.

So, it will be normal to receive an empty response, along with that status code.

Comment: so, your saying this is connecting? But why am I not getting any data in return? I need the auth key and the cancel post is not being sent. So what is my next step?

Comment: My comment was in reference to the cancel subscription post. If you are not receiving any data when requesting an access token, then that is an earlier problem you will need to troubleshoot. You can start by looking at the curl connection error.

Comment: Thats my point, Im not getting any errors to point me in the right direction. I have attempted to print the error several ways

Comment: Okay well, then I have missed adding that? I am new to using cURL and it would be helpful to have comments that point towards me fixing my issue.

Comment: You've stated that you are receiving no response. curl_error is useful to debug a connection problem, and check errors in the connection.  See the PHP documentation for details